# To show chrome extension desktop notification box when i publish rss feed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, rss, push-notification, feed

how to show chrome extension desktop notification box when i publish rss feed ?
and how to show how many numbers of feed on chrome extension icon ?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add numbers on the chrome extension icon by RSS feed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000558/how-to-add-numbers-on-the-chrome-extension-icon-by-rss-feed)

Answer (score 0):

desktop notification box:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html

notice that the createHTMLNotification function is not available in current version of chrome

show numbers of feed on chrome extension icon:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText